# How to perform backward pagination in cognito userpool

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-cognito

I am working with nodeJs - AWS lambda function, cognito userpool(AWS).

The requirement is of adding pagination feature, for that I am able to perform forward pagination with the help of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html,
but I am not able to find, what are the necessary steps to perform backward pagination, so that in UI, the users can scroll to previous and next pages without any issues using the endpoint created by me.

Can anyone help me into this?

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, then what you are doing is, that your lambda function is doing pagination in cognito for users by using aws nodejs SDK and you are serving that lambda using API gateway, right ?

Comment: yes, this is the flow, @KnowledgeGainer
using this, i am able to perform forward pagination, but need to do backward pagination

Answer (score 0):

Since you are directly accessing cognito API to do pagination for users,

What I would suggest is to pass a paginator value from UI to your API, that API will process your pagination in a loop,

**For Example:**

For the ease of understanding I will use pagination from 1
and each page is having 8 items,

So let's say,

You are sending querystringparameters something like this:

**[your-api-endpoint]?page=1**

Now, there is a variable **counter** which is the number of times your loop will execute,

Start a loop and in that loop call the Cognito API along with token handling capability, so if you call it 1 time you will have first 8 items.

**Now let's take another scenario:**

You are sending querystringparameters something like this:

**[your-api-endpoint]?page=2**

Now, the variable **counter** which is the number of times your loop will execute is set to **2**,

Start a loop and in that loop call the Cognito API along with token handling capability, so if you call it you will have first 8 items, and loop will execute one more time since counter is set to 2, therefore you will have next 8 items and you can return that.

In this way your pagination will depend on input from **front-end**.

Comment: This is doable using paginationtoken and limit in user pool, the place where I am stuck is going backward to previous page, referring to the example to shared, if I want to go back to page 1 from page 2, what can be done here, any suggestions?

Comment: The above solution works for that also, you just have to send parameter as 1 and it will send the results of page 1

Comment: This will work if I have all data fetched already from user pool, so that I can loop through each entry and send the response, but it will create trouble when I will be having large set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I cannot found any specific sdk or code to implement backward pagination in cognito user pool, I have taken help of front end to store the pagination token sent from backend and fetch data accordingly.

So the scenario will be : For first time calling the API, the pagination token value(in headers/or the place where it is kept(params/body/headers)) will be NULL, and response will get a paginationtoken to move to next page, it can be stored in UI code, and use it to move to next page, again response will receive a paginationtoken, store it and proceed further to fetch next page data.

In order to move back to the previous page, use the stored pagination token and fetch the details accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).